# php include file based on day of the week - concise code?

Tags: arrays, date, include, dayofweek, days

I've used answers to some of the previous questions on stack overflow (thanks everyone) to come up with an associative array that includes a particular file based on the day of the week but I was wondering if there is a way of making the code more concise as the path names seem long and repetitive?

$today = date("l");

$content = array (

"Sunday" => "/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/sundays-activities-home.php",
"Monday" => "/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/mondays-activities-home.php",
"Tuesday" => "/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/thursdays-activities-home.php",
"Wednesday" => "/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/wednesdays-activities-home.php",
"Thursday" => "/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/thursdays-activities-home.php",
"Friday" => "/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/fridays-activities-home.php",
"Saturday" => "/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/saturdays-activities-home.php"

);
 
include $content[$today];

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Elaborate, ok, well as a newcomer I'm aware that if I find myself repeating something there it's usually a shorter way to achieve the same thing. It feels like I'm repeating a similar path name so I was wondering if there is a shorter way to write this code? Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following snippet.

```
$today = date( 'l' );
$file = '/home/josull05/htdocs/wdd4/php/main-content/' . strtolower( $today ) . 's-activities-home.php';
include( $file );
```

Variable `$today` will get day name like `Sunday`,`Monday`. In the file name we need day name in small, so `strtolower` is used.

Note: It will be safe to check existence of file before inclusion. You can use `file_exists`.

Comment: Thank you, that has helped and expanded my understanding of the language.